# Xamarin forms app crashes showing memory overflow error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Below is the error :

```
 05-01 01:36:39.414 I/art     ( 4758): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.430 I/art     ( 4758): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 15.801ms for cause Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.430 I/art     ( 4758): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.459 I/art     ( 4758): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.477 I/art     ( 4758): Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-01 01:36:39.477 I/art     ( 4758): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 17.695ms for cause Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.477 I/art     ( 4758): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.483 I/art     ( 4758): Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.487 I/art     ( 4758): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.487 I/art     ( 4758): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.503 I/art     ( 4758): Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-01 01:36:39.503 I/art     ( 4758): Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 192(7KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 719us total 15.608ms
05-01 01:36:39.503 I/art     ( 4758): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.507 I/art     ( 4758): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.522 I/art     ( 4758): Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-01 01:36:39.522 I/art     ( 4758): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8(256B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 599us total 15.143ms
05-01 01:36:39.522 I/art     ( 4758): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 42KB allocation
05-01 01:36:39.522 I/art     ( 4758): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.538 I/art     ( 4758): Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-01 01:36:39.539 I/art     ( 4758): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 467us total 16.050ms
05-01 01:36:39.539 W/art     ( 4758): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 43612 byte allocation with 20680 free bytes and 20KB until OOM"
05-01 01:36:39.539 I/art     ( 4758): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.539 I/art     ( 4758): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.542 I/art     ( 4758): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.557 I/art     ( 4758): Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-01 01:36:39.557 I/art     ( 4758): Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(192B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 494us total 14.784ms
05-01 01:36:39.557 I/art     ( 4758): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.571 I/art     ( 4758): Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-01 01:36:39.571 I/art     ( 4758): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1(32B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 430us total 14.253ms
05-01 01:36:39.571 I/art     ( 4758): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 42KB allocation
05-01 01:36:39.571 I/art     ( 4758): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
05-01 01:36:39.588 I/art     ( 4758): Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-01 01:36:39.588 I/art     ( 4758): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2(64B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 489us total 16.563ms
05-01 01:36:39.588 W/art     ( 4758): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 43612 byte allocation with 20680 free bytes and 20KB until OOM"
05-01 01:36:39.589 I/art     ( 4758): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 65.985ms for cause Background
```

I have tried setting the largeHeap as true in android manifest file. Also, I thought that this might be because of the images in my page, but I am getting this error even after removing all images from m page.

I have also set the java max heap size in options to 2G but problem still persists.

Here's the code

```
public partial class SingleRetailerBooking : ContentPage
{
    int expanded = 0;
    bool headertapped = false;
    string colorValueWhenSetTapped;
    AllProducts products;
    public List<String> colorList, offerMonthsListAll;
    private Dictionary<String, List<String>> colorsWithSizes = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
    public List<String> colorWithSizeList;
    private Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, int>> sizeWiseOrders = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>(); //contains all sizes values respective to the colors
    private ObservableCollection<ExpandableHeaderClass> _allGroups;
    private ObservableCollection<ExpandableHeaderClass> _expandableGroup;
    public ObservableCollection<SingleBookingDataModel> singlebookingdata { get; set; }
    string s,val;
    int selectedIndex;
    ItemCell cell = new ItemCell();
    private Button set_id;
    private Dictionary<String, int> totalQuantity;
    private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<String,int>> setForColors = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<String,int>>();
    Dictionary<String, int> OfferMonthWiseSets = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    Dictionary<String, String> optionsList = new Dictionary<String, String>();
    List<String> offerMonthList = new List<string>();
    ExpandableHeaderClass exp;
    String clicked_set_or_item_button = "";

    public SingleRetailerBooking(AllProducts product, List<String> colorList, Dictionary<String, String> optionsList, List<String> offerMonthList)
    {
        this.products = product;
        this.colorList = colorList;
        this.optionsList = optionsList;
        this.offerMonthList = offerMonthList;

        ProductsDataAccess pda = new ProductsDataAccess();
        pda.AddProductsToCart();

        Application.Current.Properties["ColorList"] = colorList;

        if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("SizeListColorwise"))
        {
            colorsWithSizes = Application.Current.Properties["SizeListColorwise"] as Dictionary<String, List<String>>;
        }

        string offerMon = product.OfferMonths;
        offerMonthList = offerMon.Split(',').ToList();

     for (int i = 0; i < colorList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (colorsWithSizes.ContainsKey(colorList[i]))
            {
                Dictionary<String, int> ordersDictionary = new Dictionary<String, int>();

                List<String> sizes = colorsWithSizes.ElementAt(i).Value;
                for (int z = 0; z < sizes.Count; z++)
                {
                    ordersDictionary.Add(sizes[z], 1);
                }
                sizeWiseOrders.Add(colorList[i], ordersDictionary);
            }

            Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            for (int a=0;a<offerMonthList.Count;a++)
            {
                dict.Add(offerMonthList[a],0);
            }

            setForColors.Add(colorList[i], dict);
        }

        Application.Current.Properties["sizeWiseOrders"] = sizeWiseOrders;
        Application.Current.Properties["setForColors"] = setForColors;

        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        InitializeComponent();
        //lstView.ItemsSource = GetItems();
        //exp = new ExpandableHeaderClass();
        //_allGroups = exp.ExpandableHeaderClassReturn();
        //UpdateListContent();
        // An Example DataSource
        //MyDataSource = new List<CarouselData>() { new CarouselData() { Name = "Screen.png" },
        //                                          new CarouselData() { Name = "fieldassistlogo.png" },
        //                                          new CarouselData() { Name = "icon.png" },
        //                                          new CarouselData() { Name = "password.png" }};

        BindingContext = this;
        TapGestureRecognizer tap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tap.Tapped += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            Page page = new NavigationPage(new BookingStatus());
            Navigation.PushAsync(page);
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(page, false);
        };
        cartImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);

        TapGestureRecognizer menuIconTapped = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        menuIconTapped.Tapped += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, "OpenMaster");
        };
        menuImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(menuIconTapped);

        TapGestureRecognizer reviewIconTapped = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        reviewIconTapped.Tapped += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            reviewgrid.IsVisible = true;
        };
        reviewImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(reviewIconTapped);

        lstView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => lstView.SelectedItem = null;

        //SetAllProductData(products);

    }

    private async  Task getTotalQuantity(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> setForColors, Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, int>> sizeWiseOrders)
    {
        int setCount = 0;
        totalQuantity = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var item in sizeWiseOrders)
        {
            foreach (var subitem in setForColors)
            {
                if (item.Key == subitem.Key)
                {
                    foreach (var set in subitem.Value)
                    {
                        int totalCount = 0;
                        setCount = set.Value;
                        Dictionary<String, int> dictNew = item.Value;
                        List<int> newList = dictNew.Values.ToList();

                        for (int z = 0; z < newList.Count; z++)
                        {
                            totalCount += setCount * newList[z];
                        }
                        totalQuantity.Add(item.Key, totalCount);
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }
        Application.Current.Properties["totalQuantity"] = totalQuantity;

    }

    //public List<CarouselData> MyDataSource { get; set; } // Must have default value or be set before the BindingContext is set.

    //private int _position;
    //public int Position { get { return _position; } set { _position = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    private void close(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numbergrid.IsVisible = false;
        cancelandsavegrid.IsVisible = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < _allGroups.Count; i++)
        {
            _allGroups[i].Expanded = false;
        }
        UpdateListContent();
    }

    private async Task Number_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button id = null;
        String labelText = "";
        if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("ExpandableItemCellButtonId"))
        {
            if (!Application.Current.Properties["ExpandableItemCellButtonId"].ToString().Equals(""))
            {
                id = Application.Current.Properties["ExpandableItemCellButtonId"] as Button;
                labelText = Application.Current.Properties["ExpandableItemCellLabelText"] as String;
                clicked_set_or_item_button = "itemButtonClicked";
            }
        }

        Button d = (Button)sender;
        s = d.Text;
        if (id != null && clicked_set_or_item_button.Equals("itemButtonClicked"))
        {
            id.Text = s;
            if (sizeWiseOrders.ContainsKey(val))
            {
                Dictionary<String, int> dict = sizeWiseOrders[val];
                if (dict.ContainsKey(labelText))
                {
                    dict[labelText] = Int32.Parse(s);
                }
            }
        }
        if (set_id != null && clicked_set_or_item_button.Equals("setClicked"))
        {
            set_id.Text = s;
            var colorValue = set_id.CommandParameter.ToString();

            if (offerMonthList.Count==1)
            {
                setForColors[colorValue][offerMonthList[0]] = Int32.Parse(s);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        await getTotalQuantity(setForColors, sizeWiseOrders);
        List<int> values = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in totalQuantity)
        {
            values.Add(item.Value);
        }

        for (int i=0; i< _allGroups.Count; i++)
        {
            if (values.Count > 0)
                _allGroups[i].Quantity = values[i];
            else
                _allGroups[i].Quantity = 0;
        }

        UpdateListContent();
    }

    //private void saveOrder(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    ProductsDataAccess pda = new ProductsDataAccess();
    //    pda.AddProductsToCart();


    //}

    public void HeaderTapped(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        val = btn.CommandParameter.ToString();
        Application.Current.Properties["selectedIndexColor"] = val;

        for (int i=0;i<colorList.Count;i++)
        {
            if (colorList[i]==val)
            {
                selectedIndex = i;
                Application.Current.Properties["selectedIndex"] = selectedIndex;
            }
        }

        _allGroups[selectedIndex].Expanded = !_allGroups[selectedIndex].Expanded;
        expanded = selectedIndex;
        UpdateListContent();
        if (headertapped)
        { 
                cancelandsavegrid.IsVisible = false;
                numbergrid.IsVisible = true;
                headertapped = false;
        }
        else{
                cancelandsavegrid.IsVisible = true;
                numbergrid.IsVisible = false;
                headertapped = true;
        }
    }

    public void SetTapped(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Application.Current.Properties["ExpandableItemCellButtonId"] = "";
        clicked_set_or_item_button = "setClicked";
        set_id = (Button)sender;
        colorValueWhenSetTapped = set_id.CommandParameter.ToString();
        numbergrid.IsVisible = true;
        cancelandsavegrid.IsVisible = false;
    }

    private void Review_Cancel_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reviewgrid.IsVisible = false;
    }

    private void UpdateListContent()
    {
        int count = 0;
        _expandableGroup = new ObservableCollection<ExpandableHeaderClass>();

        foreach (ExpandableHeaderClass group in _allGroups)
        {  
            ExpandableHeaderClass newgroup = new ExpandableHeaderClass(group.Name, group.Set, group.Quantity, group.Expanded);
            if (group.Expanded)
            {       
                headertapped = true;
                count = count + 1;
                foreach (Child child in group)
                {
                    newgroup.Add(child);
                }
            }
            _expandableGroup.Add(newgroup);
        }
        lstView.HeightRequest = colorList.Count * 60 + count * 100;
        lstView.ItemsSource = _expandableGroup;
    }

    private async Task SetAllProductData(AllProducts product)
    {
        ProductName.Text = products.Name;
        Description.Text = products.Description;
        BrandName.Text = product.Brand;
        StypeName.Text = product.SubCategory;
        //OfferMonthName.Text = product.OfferMonths;
        CategoryName.Text = product.Category;
        GenderName.Text = product.Gender;
        MRPValue.Text = product.MRP;
        CollectionName.Text = product.Collection;
        FitName.Text = product.Fit;
        FabricName.Text = product.Fabric;
        FinishName.Text = product.Finish;
        MoodName.Text = product.Mood;
        OfferMonthName.Text = String.Join(",", offerMonthList);

        bool promoted = product.Promoted;
        if (promoted)
            Recommended.IsVisible = true;
        else
            Recommended.IsVisible = false;
        Productdata productData = new Productdata(product, productGrid);

        await getTotalQuantity(setForColors, sizeWiseOrders);

    }

    public async void SaveOrder(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        int setcount = 0;
        //for (int i=0;i<setForColors.Count;i++)
        //{
        //    setcount += setForColors[i];
        //}

        foreach (var newitem in setForColors)
        {
            foreach (var subitem in newitem.Value)
            {
                setcount += subitem.Value;
            }
        }

        if (setcount==0)
        {
            //await DisplayAlert("","Please enter atleat one set","OK");
            await Navigation.PopAsync();

            var existingPages = Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();

            Page Qrpage = new NavigationPage(new QRScanningPage());
            await Navigation.PushAsync(Qrpage);
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(Qrpage, false);
        }
        else
        {

            Dictionary<String, int> dict1;
            Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, int>> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<String, int>>();

            foreach (var setColors in setForColors)
            {
                foreach (var sizeOrders in sizeWiseOrders)
                {
                    if (sizeOrders.Key == setColors.Key)
                    {
                        dict1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                        foreach (var item1 in setColors.Value)
                        {
                            int count = 0;
                            foreach (var item2 in sizeOrders.Value)
                            {
                                count += item1.Value * item2.Value;
                            }
                            dict1.Add(item1.Key, count);
                        }
                        dict2.Add(sizeOrders.Key, dict1);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in optionsList)
            {
                foreach (var subItem in sizeWiseOrders)
                {
                    if (item.Key == subItem.Key)
                    {
                        Dictionary<String, int> dict = sizeWiseOrders[item.Key];
                        Dictionary<String, int> quantityWithSets = dict2[item.Key];
                        Dictionary<String, int> sets = setForColors[item.Key];
                        string result = string.Join(";", dict.Select(m => m.Key + ":" + m.Value).ToArray());
                        String setResult = string.Join(";", sets.Select(m => m.Key + ":" + m.Value).ToArray());

                        String quantityString = string.Join(";", quantityWithSets.Select(m => m.Key + ":" + m.Value).ToArray());
                        var orderDetails = new RetailerBookingModel()
                        {
                            Option = item.Value,
                            Name = products.Name,
                            Price = Int32.Parse(products.MRP),
                            Description = products.Description,
                            Brand = products.Brand,
                            Category = products.Category,
                            ColorList = item.Key,
                            SizeWiseRatios = result,
                            Sets = setResult,
                            QuantityWithSets = quantityString,
                            Quantity = totalQuantity[item.Key],
                            Fit = products.Fit,
                            Collection = products.Collection

                        };
                        App.DAUtil.SaveSingleRetailerBooking(orderDetails);
                    }
                }
            }

            await Navigation.PopAsync();

            Page Qrpage = new NavigationPage(new QRScanningPage());
            await Navigation.PushAsync(Qrpage);
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(Qrpage, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code associated to this? This is basically just guessing what is going on here.

Comment: added the code..

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the Heapsize to 1G in android->Properties

Comment: done that and also changed the heap to large in android manifest file